# mklink error on domain connected machine but valid symlink still created - "the system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: windows, cmd, symlink, mklink

On domain connected Windows 10 and Windows 8.1 machines (issue may not be version specific), running `mklink symlinkToCreate.txt originalFile.txt` is producing an error `The system cannot find the file specified`. The symlink is still created correctly.

I have made sure that `originalFile.txt` *does exist* and that `symlinkToCreate.txt` *does not already exist*.  I have also tried using absolute paths for both parts instead of relative paths. I am using an *elevated* command prompt as I know that only elevated Administrators can create symlinks by default. I have also checked the `Create symbolic links` local policy and confirmed that this is just set to *Administrators*.

Directory link creation also produces the error (`mklink /D`). Hard link creation, however, works fine (`mklink /H`).

Weirdly, I get the same behaviour even when logged in using the local Administrator account. I also get the same behaviour on a different machine in the same domain. The *exact same commands* work perfectly on a non domain-connected machine.

Given that mklink is built into cmd and that the file I'm linking definitely exists, I'm stumped as to what file the system cannot find, though I strongly suspect that the actual content of the error is a red herring. Shame there doesn't seem to be a mklink debug mode!

Any pointers greatly appreciated as I'm banging my head against a wall with this one.